# g++: std::function initialized with closure type always uses heap allocation?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, std-function

Some sources on the Internets (specifically [this one](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/efficient-use-of-lambda-expressions-and/232500059)) says that std::function use small-closure optimizations, e.g. it do not allocate heap if closure size is lower than some amount of data (link above indicates 16 bytes for gcc)

So I went digging through g++ headers

Looks like whether or not such optimization is applied is decided by this block of code in "functional" header (g++ 4.6.3)

```
static void
_M_init_functor(_Any_data& __functor, _Functor&& __f)
{ _M_init_functor(__functor, std::move(__f), _Local_storage()); }
```

and some lines down:

```
static void
_M_init_functor(_Any_data& __functor, _Functor&& __f, true_type)
{ new (__functor._M_access()) _Functor(std::move(__f)); }

static void
_M_init_functor(_Any_data& __functor, _Functor&& __f, false_type)
{ __functor._M_access<_Functor*>() = new _Functor(std::move(__f)); }
  };
```

e.g if _Local_storage() is true_type, than placement-new is called, otherwise - regular new

defintion of _Local_storage is the folowing:

```
typedef integral_constant<bool, __stored_locally> _Local_storage;
```

and __stored_locally:

```
static const std::size_t _M_max_size = sizeof(_Nocopy_types);
static const std::size_t _M_max_align = __alignof__(_Nocopy_types);

static const bool __stored_locally =
(__is_location_invariant<_Functor>::value
 && sizeof(_Functor) <= _M_max_size
 && __alignof__(_Functor) <= _M_max_align
 && (_M_max_align % __alignof__(_Functor) == 0));
```

and finally: __is_location_invariant:

```
template<typename _Tp>
struct __is_location_invariant
: integral_constant<bool, (is_pointer<_Tp>::value
               || is_member_pointer<_Tp>::value)>
{ };
```

So. as far as I can tell, closure type is neither a pointer nor a member pointer. To verify that I even wrote a small test program:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << "max stored locally size: " << sizeof(std::_Nocopy_types) << ", align: " << __alignof__(std::_Nocopy_types) << std::endl;

  auto lambda = [](){};

  typedef decltype(lambda) lambda_t;

  std::cout << "lambda size: " << sizeof(lambda_t) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "lambda align: " << __alignof__(lambda_t) << std::endl;

  std::cout << "stored locally: " << ((std::__is_location_invariant<lambda_t>::value
     && sizeof(lambda_t) <= std::_Function_base::_M_max_size
     && __alignof__(lambda_t) <= std::_Function_base::_M_max_align
     && (std::_Function_base::_M_max_align % __alignof__(lambda_t) == 0)) ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
}
```

and the output is:

```
max stored locally size: 16, align: 8
lambda size: 1
lambda align: 1
stored locally: false
```

So, my questions is the following: is intializing std::function with lambda always results with heap allocation? or am I missing something?

Comment: I confirm your findings by this program: http://ideone.com/kzae6U You can check on clang (http://melpon.org/wandbox/) that the same program only does memory allocation for very big capture...

Answer (score 7):

As of GCC 4.8.1, the std::function in libstdc++ optimizes only for pointers to functions and methods. So regardless the size of your functor (lambdas included), initializing a std::function from it triggers heap allocation. Unfortunately there is no support for custom allocators either.

Visual C++ 2012 and LLVM libc++ do avoid allocation for any sufficiently small functor.

Note, for this optimization to kick in your functor should fulfill std::is_nothrow_move_constructible. This is to support noexcept std::function::swap(). Fortunately, lambdas satisfy this requirement if all captured values do.

You can write a simple program to check behavior on various compilers:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// noexpect missing in MSVC11
#ifdef _MSC_VER
# define NOEXCEPT
#else
# define NOEXCEPT noexcept
#endif

struct A
{
    A() { }
    A(const A&) { }
    A(A&& other) NOEXCEPT { std::cout << "A(A&&)\n"; }

    void operator()() const { std::cout << "A()\n"; }

    char data[FUNCTOR_SIZE];
};

int main()
{
    std::function<void ()> f((A()));
    f();

    // prints "A(A&&)" if small functor optimization employed
    auto f2 = std::move(f); 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I bet if you added this:

```
std::cout << "std::__is_location_invariant: " << std::__is_location_invariant<lambda_t>::value << std::endl;
```

you would get back:

```
std::__is_location_invariant: 0
```

At least that's what [ideone says](http://ideone.com/3ttpp).

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much implies from my test. Question is: this is final? Dr. Dobbs is wrong and we always have heap allocations?

Comment: @AlexI., it really depends on the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

std::function's allocation is an implementation detail; however last I checked, 12 bytes is the max functor size for msvc, 16 for gcc, 24 for boost+msvc.

Comment: adzm: yes, this is mentioned in the link in the beginning of the question. However, I do not see this is actually the case with g++