# C++ Declaring An Array Of Function Pointers

Tags: c++

Basically I need to implement an event handler class, but run into an error that I cannot declare an array of voids:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    void registerEventHandler(int event, void (*handler)(std::string));

private:
    // here i get this error: declaration of ‘eventHandlers’ as array of void
    void (*eventHandlers)(std::string)[TOTAL_EVENTS];
}

void SomeClass::registerEventHandler(int event, void (*handler)(std::string))
{
    eventHandlers[event] = handler;
}



void handler1(std::string response)
{
    printf("ON_INIT_EVENT handler\n");
}
void handler2(std::string response)
{
    printf("ON_READY_EVENT handler\n");
}

void main()
{
    someClass.registerEventHandler(ON_INIT_EVENT, handler1);
    someClass.registerEventHandler(ON_READY_EVENT, handler2);
}
```

Can you help me figure out the exact syntax?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not array of voids. It's array of function pointers.
You should have defined it as follows:

```
void (*eventHandlers[TOTAL_EVENTS])(std::string);
```

Or better (C++14):

```
using event_handler = void(*)(std::string);
event_handler handlers[TOTAL_EVENTS];
```

Or C++03:

```
typedef void(*event_handler)(std::string);
event_handler handlers[TOTAL_EVENTS];
```

But I would rather recommend to do it using vector:

```
using event_handler = void(*)(std::string);
std::vector<event_handler> handlers;
```

Comment: Also, consider `using event_handler = std::function<void(std::string)>` - it will accept a larger number of callable objects, not just functions but also lambda expressions etc.

Comment: ...and add a huge overhead

Comment: @cubuspl42 True. But not always. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452022/g-stdfunction-intialized-with-closure-type-always-uses-heap-allocation

Answer (score 3):

You are defining `eventHandles` as a pointer to a function returning an array of 5 `void`s, which is not what you intended.

Instead of trying to do this in one line, it will be easier and more readable by using a `typedef`:

```
typedef void (*event_handler_t)(std::string);
event_handler_t eventHandlers[TOTAL_EVENTS];
```

Answer (score 3):

You mixed the event handler type and the array definition. Separate with typedef:

```
typedef void(*eventHandler)(std::string);
eventHandler eventHandlers[TOTAL_EVENTS];
```