# Lambda function performance impact of capture

Tags: c++, lambda

I just wrote a pretty big capture:

```
[this, &newIndex, &indexedDirs, &filters, &flags, &indexRecursion](){...
```

I use this lambda (indexRecursion) for a recursion with thoudands of elements and asked myself, if it would be more efficient to use the "global" capture `[&]`. Since I have no clue of the implementation of the capture I need some explanation. Please with background too.

Comment: implementation defined. there is no correct answer. if performance is a problem, rethink the algorithm.

Comment: `&` probably has the same effect as explicitly capturing everything that you actually use, so it won't be faster.

Comment: Note that with the global capture `[&]`, you will capture `this` by reference and potentially introduces an other indirection.

Comment: [Does the C++ standard force capturw-by-reference of local variables to be inefficient?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31318762/1708801) is probably relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually you can think of a lambda as equivalent to this:

```
class ANON {
  int data;
  public:
    void operator ()(void) const {
      cout << data << endl;
    }
} lambda;
// auto lambda = [data]() {cout << data << endl;}
```

This should give you an idea of how capture is implemented. Capture all (be it by copy `=` or reference `&`) will probably be no more than syntactic sugar for specifying all used/available variables for capture in the current scope.

But since ...

> [..] An implementation may define the closure type differently from what is described below provided this does not alter the observable behavior of the program other than by changing: [..] the size and/or alignment of the closure type [..]
>
> [N4431 §5.1.2/3]

... it would be legal for an implementation to use some sort of "black magic" for capture all by reference lambdas and just use a pointer to the captured stack frame, rewriting accesses to the variables as accesses to some offset of that pointer:

```
class ANON {
  void * stack_frame;
  public:
    void operator ()(void) const {
      cout << *static_cast<int *>(stack_frame + 8) << endl;
    }
} lambda;
```

So using `&` *might* (some day) be more efficient, but as already said this is implementation defined and this nothing to be relied upon.

Answer (score 2):

Internally lambdas are /usually/ implemented as ad-hoc classes  whose single instance object is constructed in the point of lambda definition and which are exposing a functor to be called later. So lambda performance should be compared with passing a method to a function using `std::bind`.

Captures aren't mystical entities as well. If captures are reference-captures, entities which they refer to are detroyed when go out of the scope as usual, so beware if your lambda isn't local: inside its body it may refer to object which have been destroyed already.

Comment: Just a note. To avoid the deletion of a captured variable, define it as a `shared_ptr` and inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this`.